# Mercurial lock when cloning over a filesystem

Tags: windows, mercurial

When cloning a Mercurial repository over http in a Windows environment, I get the following output:

```
hg clone http:/myserver/hg/repo hgcopy
  requesting all changes
  adding changesets
  adding manifests
  adding file changes
  added xxx changesets with xxx changes to 92985 files
  updating to branch default
  92985 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

Cloning over the filesystem, i.e. over a shared network drive, gives a complete different output:

```
c:\Hg>hg clone \\server\Hg\Repo c:\Hg\Repo
   copying [   <=>                                   ] 23712
   updating to branch default
   92985 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

This last operation is 3x times faster, but creates a lock file in the remote repo, making it impossible to start a second clone from another system. The Mercurial [docs about Locking Design](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/LockingDesign) do not reveal much info about it:

> Possible problems can occur if a reader reads files out of order. For instance, copying a repository with other tools (rsync, for instance) during a pull or commit may result in copying a changelog refers to a manifest entry that isn't in the copy.

So, what kind of mechanism is going on when cloning over the filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not *stack traces*, they are just ordinary output.

Mercurial locks the source repository when using "fast copy" cloning via copy or hard-link precisely *because* this does not use the slower "pull protocol".  You can run:

```
hg clone --pull \\server\Hg\Repo c:\Hg\Repo
```

to force Mercurial to use the pull protocol anyway: see `hg help --verbose clone` for details.  This will be slower than direct-copy, though probably not nearly as slow as cloning via `http` or `https` (since HTTP requires passing all the data through your web server).